# Record video using ffmpeg on mac os

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, video-recording

I want to record live webcam video on mac OS using ffmpeg in any format. I tried a lot but not able to find out command for recoding of  video. So Please any one can tell me ffmpeg command for capture video using web cam for mac os.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: A later question (a duplicate of this one) got a better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966994/record-a-video-with-isight-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 3):

for mac os try:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "0" -f mpeg1video -b:v 800k -r 30
```

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg **can't** record using the iSight camera.

But, this dude shows [how to record a time lapse video on Mac](http://www.carbonsilk.com/development/timelapse-video-mac/) using the cmd-line.